# Generate a line graph in Amazon QuickSight comparing the data for 2 weeks or 2 months or 2 years according to the end-user's desire

Tags: data-visualization, linegraph, amazon-quicksight

I would like to show visualization in the form of a line graph having the day names from Monday to Sunday on the x-axis and the activity of the student in the form of tests and videos on the y-axis. There should be 2 lines representing this metric for 2 consecutive weeks/months/years.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Yes, I generated a visualization as a clustered combo bar chart in Amazon QickSight.